# Допустимо ли выражение «протяну ещё сколько-то времени»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли выражение "протяну ещё сколько-то времени"
или вариант "протяну ещё какое-то время" единственно правильный?

Comment: спасибо большое всем

Answer (score 1):

Тут одной фразой-то и не ответишь. Пожалуй так. В разговорном стиле оно допустимо. А вариант "ещё какое-то" не единственный, но предпочтительный.

Тут интересный момент. В классических грамматиках "сколько" относилось только к объектам счетным. Время категорией счетности не обладало. Отсюда и отношение к сочетаниям типа "Сколько времени?" и подобным как к неправильным или (как минимум) к нерекомендуемым.
Сейчас, мало того, что фразы типа "сколько тебе надо времени (воды, сена, железа)" выглядят абсолютно законными, так еще и "время" перестало восприниматься как исключительно линейный объект (короткое время, долгое время), став чем-то имеющим этакую "абстрактную" размерность (много времени, мало времени), чем вопрос о "сколько" и снимается.

Однако в силу инерции язык несколько сопротивляется тотальному переходу измерения времени в категорию "сколько". Этим и объясняется моя рекомендация, с которой я начал.

Ей и закончу.

***"Протяну ещё сколько-то времени"*** — допустимо, преимущественно в разговорной речи.
***"Протяну ещё какое-то время"*** — желательный и стилистически безупречный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, такое сочетание вполне допустимо. Для себя пояснил так:

**Он сделает это *тогда*-то**.

Здесь неопределенное местоимение было образовано с помощью указательного **тогда**. **Значение**: определенный момент времени.

**Он сделает это *когда*-то**.

В этом же случае неопределенное местоимение образуется с помощью относительно-вопросительного (здесь оно относительное) **когда**. **Значение**: неопределенный момент времени.

Следуя этой логике, можно предположить, что для каждого неопределенного местоимения, образованного с помощью частицы -то и обладающего **некоторым значением**, есть ещё одно, но имеющее **значение, противоположное данному**. Отсюда находим пару:

**Столько-то / сколько-то**.